# Getting an undefined data and the "Query data cannot be undefined" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-query

I am using **Next.js** to build a project for my portfolio. And, I am trying to use **Tanstack query** along with **Axios** to handle the **API**.

The problem is, I am getting an error while I'm trying to fetch the data. The data gets fetched from the API and I can see it when I **console.log** it inside the function. But when I try to access it outside the function, it returns **undefined**.

Here's my code for the function:

```
const Home = () => {

  const {data} = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['products'],
  
    queryFn: async () => {
      const res = await axios.get(
        'https://fakestoreapi.com/products'
      )
      const data = await res.data
      console.log(data)
      //can access data here
    }
  })
  
  console.log(data)
  //cannot access data here and returns undefined.

  return (
    <section>
      //some codes here
    </section>
  )
}
```

I am also getting this error in the console:

> Query data cannot be undefined. Please make sure to return a value
> other than undefined from your query function. Affected query key:
> ["products"]

I have looked everywhere for the fix and found no clue what is causing this. Can someone help me fix this?

**Side note:** I can get the data when using a normal fetch request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are passing as a value to `queryFn` is returning nothing, hence when it resolves, it returns `undefined`. This should work:

```
const Home = () => {
  const { data } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["products"],
    queryFn: async () => {
      const res = await axios.get("https://fakestoreapi.com/products");
      return res.data;
    },
  });

  return <section>{/* some codes here */}</section>;
};
```